# Visual Studios does not allow me to view my Form.cs [Design]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am learning to write in C# on Visual Studios and everything has been going well until today when i was trying to run my app

(using Ctrl + F5). After I tried to run my app it would not run and prompted me to save. Unfortunately I did not pay to much attention and tried to save it but an error message came up saying something like, "There already exists a file named form1.designer. Would you like to replace this file?" I was worried to replace the file so I saved it in a new location.Now when I

look at my solution explorer my original form1.designer.cs is not usable and a new form1.designer has been added.

I am no longer able to go to design view where i can edit the GUI(when i use form1.designer.cs), when i do it displays a blank form. When i try to open my design view from the lower form1.designer, it takes me to the code where the Components are initialize. The program still works perfectly when i run it, i just can't edit the GUI.

Comment: its telling you theres something wrong in the code in the designer - view it codewise and see if you can spot an obvious error

Comment: When saying "The program still works perfectly when i run it,", are you sure that you're running the program compiled from the current source code and not the last build?

Comment: Please capitalize your question properly, and [no "_Thanks"_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I am sure that it is not running on the last build when I run my program. Normally in Visual studios there is a red line that appears next to the error when a mistake is made so i don't think it is an obvious error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was a linking problem between the form and the design GUI. I had to right click on the solution, click add, existing item, and then i had to select the item i wanted to link. In this case it was the ".cs" file.